# float puts submit button outside of div

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble with my css, I have a content id and then inside that I have a class that is just padding. When inside the padding class, I have a textarea and a submit button. By default, the submit button is on the left: [image]
But when I go to align the submit button to either the left or right of the content, it will go ther ebut it will also go outside of the content, like it's not part of it anymore:
[image]
These are my html and css codes

html:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="content-padding">
            <textarea class="content-post" placeholder="Update your status..."></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="content-submit">
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#content {
    width: 60%;
    background: #dddddd;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: auto;

}
.content-padding {
    padding: 10px;
}
.content-post {
    width: 97.5%;
    height: 80px;
    border: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    resize: none;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.content-submit {
    background: #005ddb;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}
```

I hope someone cal help me fix this as soon as possible, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to trigger the layout of `.content-padding` or add a clearing element.

```
.content-padding {
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden ; /* minds inside and outside floatting elements, fine if no size given */
}
```

or a generated clearing element.

```
.content-padding:after {
    content:'';
    display:block; /* or whatever else than inline */
   clear:both;
}
```

Learn more about floatting elements : http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: that seemed pretty easy, first one worked. Thanks! (i'll select as answer in 10 mins)

Answer (score 5):

add `overflow: auto` under `#content` in your CSS.

Another option would be to add another `div` in your markup right after the submit button.

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

In your CSS you would then add the following.

```
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnHL6/)

Comment: it works but adds an overflow bar, not something I really wanna have there as it looks really bad, thanks for answering tho

Comment: You're right. I made another suggestion and added a fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a div with clear:both style after the button:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="content-padding">
        <textarea class="content-post" placeholder="Update your status..."></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="content-submit">
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The float attribute makes the height of element zero, then the parent div do not recognize the height of element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#content:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
}
```

From http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because you do not have a static height set for #content. If you set a static height for content ( padding + textArea + submitButton ) and set that as the height for #content, then it will look allow the room for everything.

```
#content {
width: 60%;
background: #dddddd;
color: #000;
margin: 0 auto;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
height: 140px; //Play with this number to get it perfect.
```

}

Comment: Thankyou for trying to help, I got it solves, and adding a static height will make things worse as I use the #content div for more than one purposes, it's not just for this. But thanks for answering, free upvote!

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I suppose I was missing the proper context :P but in this particular instance it would fix it :P